# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable Python read file

Tags: python

This is a magic square program that can find out if any size matrix is a magic square.  When i run the code i get error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.  I decided to change line = int(i) to line = i but that just gave me another error. Cant use numpy

EDIT: Now i get this error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

text file:

```
1 1
6 8
```

Here is code:

```
def main():
    filNam = "matrix8.txt"
    matrix = (readMatrix(filNam))
    rowNum = 0
    colNum = 0
    print(rowSum(matrix, rowNum))

def readMatrix(filNam):
    matrixList = []
    numFile = open(filNam, "r")
    lines = numFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        row = []
        for i in line:
            row.append(int(i))
        matrixList.append(row)
    return matrixList

def eachNumPresent(matrix):
    if len(matrix) % 2 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def rowSum(matrix, rowNum):
    for row in matrix[rowNum]:
        row = sum(int(row))
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    return i


def colSum(matrix):
    length = len(matrix)
    col_rows = 0
    for i in range(length):
        col_rows = col_rows + matrix[i][0]
        return col_rows

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the matrix gets "flatten" into one long row. In order to fix it you should read & construct the matrix row-by-row.

Change:

```
def readMatrix(filNam):
    matrixList = []
    numFile = open(filNam, "r")
    lines = numFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        for i in line:
            line = int(i)
            matrixList.append(line)
    return matrixList
```

to:

```
def readMatrix(filNam):
    matrixList = []
    numFile = open(filNam, "r")
    lines = numFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        row = []  # 1st change
        for i in line:
            row.append(int(i)) # 2nd change
        matrixList.append(row) #3rd change
    return matrixList
```

changing the code and running it on the input provided in the question it prints `2` which is the sum of the first row in the matrix.